# Images.xcassets not working for specific devices in universal application Xcode 5, iOS 7

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I'm updating iOS 6 universal application (for both - iPhone and iPad) to iOS 7 and I want to use Images.xcassets to store images in it.

For universal images (like some buttons which are the same on iPhone and iPad) this storage is working properly. But for the device specific images it is not working and I'm getting following errors on iPhone simulator:

```
CUICatalog: Can't find rendition for name: search_next scale factor: 2 device idiom: 1 device subtype: 568
Could not load the "search_next" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "sk.company.app"
```

But the image is there:

[image: specific device assets]

When I add universal image to this asset, it is working:

[image: universal device asset]

I tried this same in blank application and it's working perfectly fine, so I think it's something wrong with options, but I can't figure out where.

I more hint: the first scenario (only specific images in asset) is working, when I switch universal app to iPhone only app in project settings.

Answer (score 1):

For Universal Application always use naming convention recommended by Apple. For example you have a button image, **place images for both iPhone and iPad** e.g.

***Button~iphone.png
Button@2x~iphone.png
and For iPad
Button~ipad.png
Button@2x~ipad.png***

When you will do that you will not get error **"CUICatalog: Can't find rendition for name:"** Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it had something to do with CocoaPods. After update, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is given in the error message:

> "Could not load the 'search_next' image referenced from a nib
>   in the bundle …"

If you look at your screenshot, you'll see that the image is named "search_next@2x **-2** .png", where it should be named "search_next@2x.png". The "-2" has probably been added when you dragged another image somewhere, while the @2x version was already present.

If you solved it by updating CocoaPods it was an issue of a library, but the solution has really nothing to do with CocoaPods.